# Map to Serializable in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

NHibernate has a "Serializable" type

```
<property name="PropertyName" column="ColumnName" type="**Serializable**"  />
```

Is there a built in type for this in Fluent NHibernate?

Something like

```
Map(x => x.PropertyName).CustomType<**SerializableType**>();
```

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map(c => c.PropertyName).CustomType<NHibernate.Type.SerializableType>()
```

seems to do it

Comment: Nice!  Silly me, I should have tried that, but I guess I thought there was an equivalent in the Fluent project.

Comment: Compiles but throws Exception @ runtime

Comment: @statichippo - is the type of property `[Serializable]`?

Answer (score 2):

Map(c => c.PropertyName).CustomType("serializable");