# Mapping to SerializableType in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object with a property that I'd like to map as Serializable.  NHibernate supports this:

```
<property name="FeeGenerator" column="FeeGenerator" type="Serializable"  />
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Fluent NHibernate?

There's an SO question ([Map to Serializable in Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000798/map-to-serializable-in-fluent-nhibernate)) that would seem to address this, but the only response there doesn't work for me.

If I set

```
CustomType<NHibernate.Type.SerializableType>();
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Could not instantiate IType SerializableType: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody seems to know the answer to this.  I did find the answer, and I figured I'd share it.

Basically, you can use the **CustomType** method to map to any NHibernate type just like you would in XML because there's an overload that takes a string.  So the following

```
CustomType("Serializable");
```

outputs

```
<property name="PropertyName" type="Serializable"> ...
```

I also blogged about this (with some background and more details) over at http://blog.statichippo.com/archive/2010/01/20/mapping-serializable-types-using-fluent-nhibernate.aspx

Comment: How about serializing to Xml rather than VARBINARY?